# Declaring multiple TypeScript variables with the same type

Tags: typescript, types, variable-types

I'm coding a large TypeScript class and I've set `noImplicitAny` to `true`. Is there any way to declare multiple variables of the same type on the same line?

I'd like to declare x and y as numbers with something like "x, y: number". But the compiler doesn't like that or anything else I've tried. Is there a better alternative to "x: number; y: number"?

Comment: Just adding that even if you do the following: let notes, signatureTypeName: string; it still does not work. In this case, notes is declared as type any and signatureTypeName as type string. You can verify all this by simply hovering over the variable, for example in Visual Studio Code. The declared type appears then in a popup.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There isn't any syntax that would accomplish this in a better way than just writing the type twice.

Comment: Thank you. That's a shame. For web components with a lot of variables, declaring each on a separate line is a pain. This is especially true for form-based components.

Comment: Alternatively, for those in denial :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232315/declaring-multiple-typescript-variables-with-the-same-type#67268415

Answer (score 27):

There is no real way to achieve what you want. If your only goal is to compress everything onto one line, you can do the following:

```
public AcccountNumber: number;public branchCode:number;
```

…but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 19):

How about this? Using [array deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with Typescript's [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).

```
let [x,y]: number[]
```

But please note that this feature is unsafe if you do not turn on [pedantic index signature check](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access).
For example, the following code will not have compile error even though it should:

```
let [x, y]: number[] = [1]
console.log(x.toString()) // No problem
console.log(y.toString()) // No compile error, but boom during runtime
```

Comment: Using this answer, we can even initialize every variables at once. The drawback being having to count them manually : `let [x, y]: number[] = Array(2).fill(1)`

Answer (score 11):

You have to specify the type on each variable:

```
let x: number, y: number
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can accept an orphan variable. [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can do this.

```
var numberArray:number[]; //orphan variable
var [n1,n2,n3,n4] = numberArray;
n1=123; //n1 is number
n1="123"; //typescript compile error
```

**Update:** Here is the Javascript code generated, when targeting ECMAScript 6.

```
var numberArray; //orphan variable
var [n1, n2, n3, n4] = numberArray;
n1 = 123; //n1 is number
```

JS Code generated when targeting ECMAScript 5, like Louis said below, it's not pretty.

```
var numberArray; //orphan variable
var n1 = numberArray[0], n2 = numberArray[1], n3 = numberArray[2], n4 = numberArray[3];
n1 = 123; //n1 is number
```

Comment: You can eliminate the orphan variable by doing `var [n1,n2,n3,n4] = [] as number[];` but I'm still not a fan of this approach because whether with your code, or with my modification, `tsc` generates 4 useless assignments for the line `var [n1,n2,n3,n4] = ...`.

Comment: I feel like this is anti-programming, and not in the spirit of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

This is another alternative I use.

```
export type CoordinatesHome = {
    lat?: number;
    long?: number;
};

export type CoordinatesAway = CoordinatesHome;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let [string1, string2]: string[] = [];
```

breaking it down:

- on the left the whole `[string1, string2]` is declared as `string[]`, implying `string1, string2` is of type `string`
- to do a destructure you need it to be assigned to something, here empty array `[]`
- on right hand  the empty array is `[undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]`
  when destructuring `string1` and `string2` gets assigned to `undefined`
- finally `string1, string2` are of type `string` with value `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

e.g. let isFormSaved, isFormSubmitted, loading: boolean = false;
this syntax only works in function block, but not outside of it in typescript export class file. Not sure why is that.

For Example:

```
export class SyntaxTest {
    
        public method1() {
            e.g. let isFormSaved, isFormSubmitted, loading: boolean = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is not true, the isFormSaved will have "any" type

Answer (score -2):

Not recommended, but:

```
interface Name {[name:string]: T } or type Name{[name:string]: T}
```

example: `type test = {[Name: string]:string}`

example:     `interface {[Name: string]:boolean}`

This works. An example is provided in the Typescript documentation for another use case.
[Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score -4):

Array destructuring can be used on both side to assign values to multipel

`[startBtn, completeBtn, againBtn] = [false, false, false];`

Comment: Where's the type declaration?

Comment: @mustaccio implicit type from value

Answer (score -7):

let notes: string = '', signatureTypeName = '';

Comment: This does not explicitly define `signatureTypeName` as a `string`; it is implicitly a `string` because that is the type of the first value assigned to it. You could initially assign anything to `signatureTypeName` and it would compile. For example, you could have done `let a: string = "", b = 4`, which defeats OP's question, where he/she stated they want both variables to be the same type.