# How to declare multiple variable of same datatype in Typescript, like we do in JavaScript as :- var a,b,c;

Tags: typescript

given an example code typescript and JavaScript variable declaration:-

```
a:number;
b:number;
c:number

/* need similar as below */
var a,b,c;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring multiple TypeScript variables with the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232315/declaring-multiple-typescript-variables-with-the-same-type)

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the type on each variable:

```
let a: number, b: number, c: number;
//or
var a: number, b: number, c: number;
```