# How can I ensure all exports are the same type?

Tags: typescript

Given a file:

```
export const hello = 'hello'
export const goodbye = 'goodbye'
```

How can I ensure that all exports in this file are of the the type string?

Comment: I don't believe there is anyway to do that.  It doesn't really make any sense to have that feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly, but you can use the type of the module export in a position where it is required to have only strings. Since modules can be self referencing, you can even add this test within teh same module:

```
//test.ts
export const hello = 'hello'
export const goodbye = 'goodbye'
export const bad = 1

type RequireStrings<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> = T
type _Test = RequireStrings<typeof import('./test')>;
// type 'typeof import(".../test")' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<"hello" | "goodbye" | "bad", string>'.
//   Types of property 'bad' are incompatible.
//     Type '1' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2344)
```

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the type to be exported. As mentioned here, [Declaring multiple TypeScript variables with the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232315/declaring-multiple-typescript-variables-with-the-same-type) you need to export all members with type specified.